# How does the Antimagic Field spell affect the caster of a Zone of Truth's ability to know whether a target succeeded or failed the save?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, antimagic-field

Wizard Alice casts [Antimagic Field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) on herself around the corner from Paladin Bob. Bob, not realising this, then walks round the corner and casts Zone of Truth on an area containing Alice.

Obviously the effects of the Zone of Truth are suspended around Alice, so she does not make any saving throws against the spell.

However, [Zone of Truth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/zone-of-truth) has the following clause:

> You know whether each creature succeeds or fails on its saving throw.

What does Bob know about Alice's success or failure of the saving throw she never made? Does he "know" that she "succeeded"? Or does he know nothing, and therefore know something has gone wrong with the spell by his conspicuous lack of knowledge about Alice's save?

Comment: I expected this question to be about an antimagic field's area including the paladin but not the zone of truth. Would the knowledge of the save penetrate the antimagic field? I may have to ask this question myself. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### He would know something was up.

*Antimagic Field* (PHB p.213) states that:

> Spells and other magical effects ... can't protrude into it.

Alice simply never entered it to begin with. She won't have to save against it until she does (by dropping or leaving the *antimagic field*).

Bob could indeed cross-check that against her known distance and *zone of truth*'s range, and thus discover shenanigans. He'd have to resort to other methods if he wanted to know exactly what was going on, though.